# Pintar linha da tabela ao receber dados especificos

Tags: php, javascript, html

Possuo este código:

```
<?php
    foreach ($controller->Lista() as $objProg) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $objProg->getplaca(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objProg->getmot(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objProg->getsaida(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objProg->getorig(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objProg->getdest(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objProg->getprev(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objProg->getcarga(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objProg->getadfin(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objProg->getagen(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $objProg->getmal(); ?></td>
        <td class="t1" ><div><?php echo $objProg->getobs(); ?></div></td>
        <td><a href="edita.php?id=<?php echo $objProg->getid();?>"><p>Alterar</p></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Preciso que, quando o `echo $objProg->getdest();` for **SP** pinte toda linha da tabela de uma cor. Alguma sugestão de como fazer isso ? Necessito de javascript mesmo ou existe algum outro método ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode fazer um `if` na tag tr.

```
<tr 
    <?php if ($objProg->getdest() == 'SP') { echo 'class="linha_destaque"'; } ?>
>
```

e cria uma classe linha_destaque no css

```
.linha_destaque{ background-color: red }
```

um exemplo do html da tabela

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Coluna 1</th>
      <th>Coluna 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="linha_destaque">
      <td>L1 - C1</td>
      <td>L1 - C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: green">
      <td>L2 - C1</td>
      <td>L2 - C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>L3 - C1</td>
      <td>L3 - C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>L4 - C1</td>
      <td>L4 - C2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

Comment: +1 pelos 59s de rapidez :D

Comment: sugeriria por um espaço antes de class: `' class="...`, assim se ele usar o PHP inline vai ficar mais "redondinho" o HTML, gerando `<td>` ou `<td class="...">` .

Comment: Fiz isso porém acho que meu css na tag `<tr>` não ta pegando, coloquei até um `!important` após o red para ver, mas nada. Testei só colocando `<tr class="...">` sem o php mas não está indo.

Comment: Algum outro teste que eu possa fazer ?

Comment: Da uma olhada http://jsbin.com/xuwacorisa/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Certo, eu entendi. A saída está ocorrendo assim `<tr class="linha_destaque">`, mas não está pintando a linha. Tentei usar na `<td>` e pintou, porém na linha não está. Não sei o que pode ser isto.

Comment: Será que esta usando algum outro arquivo de css que tenha alguma regra para `tr` ? E nesse arquivo que colocou a regra .linha_destaque esta sendo carregado por último?

Comment: Testei em uma outra tabela sem css algum só com isto e funcionou. Vou procurar o css que está impedindo. Desde já obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Adicione um if na `<tr>` que verifica se o estado é SP se sim, adicione a classe que deseja pintar a linha, do contario não faça nada.

```
<tr class="<?php if($objProg->getdest() == 'SP') echo 'especial'; ?>">
```

A sáida é algo como:

```
<tr class="especial">
```

Ou

```
<tr class="">
```

Comment: Falta fechar a tag do php

Comment: @FelipeAssunção obrigado pela correção.

Comment: Tentei deste jeito mas da a mesma coisa que a resposta a cima.